# How I can delete the fresh submission from SQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am facing problem when I want to delete the most current submission from database. I want to know how you can delete the most fresh submission from SQL database.Lets say I submit some info to my database. I have two columns in my database, one called "id" which increments whenever you add an item to the database and one called "checked" which stores the info of the items checked. On my website ([NTS](https://ntsjobresults.pk)) after you click submit, it goes to some page and shows what you just submitted. What I want is for them to have the option to delete that submission if they want.

The main Problem is how do I delete the most newest submission (like the whole row) without altering the other submission in the database.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does your table have an insert timestamp - can you just delete the record with the latest insert timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

Store the `id` of the last submission in some place. Maybe an extra table will do. Something like:

```
create table last_submission (
  user_id int primary key not null,
  last_submission_id
);
```

Then, every time you create a new submission you update this table. When the time comes to delete the last submission, just get the id from this table and perform a:

```
delete from submission where id = ...; <-- saved id here
```

Answer (score -1):

If your table has an auto-generated id field.

Then use the `mysql_insert_id()` function to get the last inserted row id.

Comment: This only works right after you inserted the row. If you want to delete the submission, for example, the next day, this method won't work.